# Can I prevent exit after my custom sys.except_hook is called?

Tags: python

Problematic code:

```
import sys
def handler(exception_type, exception_value, traceback_object):
    print(exception_type, exception_value)    
sys.excepthook = handler

defined_thing = "Redacted faster than dissenting tweets"
print(defined_thing)
print(undefined_thing)
print("I wish I got here...")
```

Result:

```
Redacted faster than dissenting tweets
<class 'NameError'> name 'undefined_thing' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Problem: can I prevent the exit and proceed having printed the error?

Comment: Was there a good reason for dragging politics here?

Comment: Absolutely not.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) (emphasis mine):

> When an exception is raised and **uncaught**, the interpreter calls
>   `sys.excepthook` with three arguments, the exception class, exception
>   instance, and a traceback object. In an interactive session this
>   happens just before control is returned to the prompt; **in a Python
>   program this happens just before the program exits**.

Your except hook will run, then the program will exit. If you want to catch exceptions, you need to use the usual [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) formula.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) for that function:

**sys.excepthook(type, value, traceback)**

*This function prints out a given traceback and exception to sys.stderr.*

It does nothing but provide additional debugging facilities.